# Why UISearchController is not released on tvOS?

Tags: tvos, uisearchcontroller

I'm using the next code to initialize a search stack:

```
- (IBAction)openSearch:(id)sender {
    TVSearchResultsController *resultsController = [TVSearchResultsController new];
    UISearchController *searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:[TVSearchResultsController new]];
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = resultsController;

    [self presentViewController:searchController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

After search controller is dismissed, both `UISearchController` and `TVSearchResultsController` stay in memory and `dealloc` will never be called, that leads to a memory leak.

I've also tried to use `UISearchContainerViewController` but results are same.

What am I doing wrong? How to initialize and present `UISearchController` properly on tvOS?